# plotlyで、グラフを縦に並べたい。

Tags: python, plotly-python

plotlyで、複数のグラフを縦一列に並べたいのですが、エラーが出て動かすことが出来ません。

プログラムの概要としましては、フォルダ内のCSVをすべて読み込み、そのCSV1つ1つを2つに分割させます。`fig.add_trace`が`for`文内に二回出てくるのは、分割したcsvを重ねて、1つのグラフとして表示させたいからです。
そして、`for`文でcsvの個数分のグラフを作成し、縦に並べたいのです。

```py
x_axis = " G"
y_axis = " D"
graphNumber = 11
file_names = glob.glob('*.csv')

def get_colorpalette(colorpalette, file_number):
    palette = sns.color_palette(
        colorpalette, file_number)
    rgb = ['rgb({},{},{})'.format(*[x*256 for x in rgb])
           for rgb in palette]
    return rgb

colors = get_colorpalette('hls', graphNumber)
fig = make_subplots(len(df_list_1), 1)

for i in range(len(df_list_1)):
    for j in range(graphNumber):
        print(i)
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=df_list_0[i][x_axis][parts_number * j:parts_number * ( j + 1)], 
                y=df_list_0[i][y_axis][parts_number * j:parts_number * ( j + 1)], 
                name='forward{:.1f}'.format(j * 0.1),
                marker={'color':colors[j]}, mode='lines'
            ), i, 1
        )
        
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=df_list_1[i][x_axis][parts_number * j:parts_number * ( j + 1)],
                y=df_list_1[i][y_axis][parts_number * j:parts_number * ( j + 1)], 
                name='backward{:.1f}'.format(j * 0.1),
                marker={'color':colors[j]}, mode='lines'
            ), i, 1
        )
fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')
fig.show()
```

エラー

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-6f8e07a27f21> in <module>
      5     for j in range(graphNumber):
      6         print(i)
----> 7         fig.add_trace(
      8             go.Scatter(
      9                 x=df_list_0[i][x_axis][parts_number * j:parts_number * ( j + 1)],

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_trace(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1646             )
   1647 
-> 1648         return self.add_traces(
   1649             data=[trace],
   1650             rows=[row] if row is not None else None,

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_traces(self, data, rows, cols, secondary_ys)
   1764         if rows is not None:
   1765             for trace, row, col, secondary_y in zip(data, rows, cols, secondary_ys):
-> 1766                 self._set_trace_grid_position(trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1767 
   1768         # Make deep copy of trace data (Optimize later if needed)

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _set_trace_grid_position(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1846 
   1847         grid_ref = self._validate_get_grid_ref()
-> 1848         return _set_trace_grid_reference(
   1849             trace, self.layout, grid_ref, row, col, secondary_y
   1850         )

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\subplots.py in _set_trace_grid_reference(trace, layout, grid_ref, row, col, secondary_y)
   1309 
   1310     if row <= 0:
-> 1311         raise Exception(
   1312             "Row value is out of range. " "Note: the starting cell is (1, 1)"
   1313         )

Exception: Row value is out of range. Note: the starting cell is (1, 1)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに `Note: the starting cell is (1, 1)` と表示されている通り、`fig.add_trace(..., i, 1)` の部分で、`i` が `0` になっている事が原因です(subplot の行・列インデックスは 1 から始まります)。なので、`for i in range(len(df_list_1)):` を `for i in range(1, len(df_list_1)+1):` にするとか `fig.add_trace(..., i+1, 1)` とする必要があります。

Comment: @metropolis  さん、今回もありがとうございました。お陰様で解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージに `Note: the starting cell is (1, 1)` と表示されている通り、`fig.add_trace(..., i, 1)` の部分で、`i` が `0` になっている事が原因です(subplot の行・列インデックスは 1 から始まります)。

なので、`for i in range(len(df_list_1)):` を `for i in range(1, len(df_list_1)+1):` にするとか `fig.add_trace(..., i+1, 1)` とする必要があります。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/76048/plotly%e3%81%a7-%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%95%e3%82%92%e7%b8%a6%e3%81%ab%e4%b8%a6%e3%81%b9%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment86137_76048) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*